# How to solve Solana custom spl token create error

Tags: solana

When I run `cargo install spl-token-cli` on my server for create spl token, I am getting error.

What is problem? I can't find solution.
what is solution?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this seems like an issue in version 0.8.0 of tiny-bip39: https://github.com/maciejhirsz/tiny-bip39/issues/30, so we'll have to update the `solana-clap-utils` library to use 0.8.1 to fix this.

In the meantime, this works on my machine using Rust 1.54.0, can you revert your Rust version and try again?